# Catch Error for Pivot filter and Exit Function

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, pivot-table

I am trying to set the pivot field to filter and if there is an error (which means that Excel cannot find the data), pop out a message error.

I tried `On Error GoTo ErrMsg` but exits the function whether or not the filter had an error.

```vb
If country = "All" Then

Else
    With Sheet6.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Operator Country")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    On Error GoTo ErrMsg
    Sheet6.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Operator Country").CurrentPage _
      = country
    Exit Function 
    
ErrMsg:
    MsgBox ("No data on " & country & "!")

End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could suspend error handling for this particular task and then check if an error was raised or not by checking the `Err.Number` property.

For example:

```
On Error Resume Next
Sheet6.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Operator Country").CurrentPage = country

'check if error occurred
If Err.Number > 0 then
    MsgBox ("No data on " & country & "!")
End If

'resume normal error handling here
```

Comment: Do I have to declare Err.Number Property?

Comment: No, its a built-in property of the global `Err` object.